# Dynamic checkboxes and dropdown in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this global `List` array to which i'm passing the data from api on OnInit method.

```
List: any;
visibility:any;
Status:any;

ngOnInit(): void {
 let param = {...};
 this.Service.getUser(param).subscribe(result => {
      this.List = result['response'];
 });
}
```

> ```
> now creating dynamic checkboxes and dropdowns
> ```

```
       <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let user of List;let i = index">
                      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="visibility[i]">
                      {{ user.Name }} 
                        <select name="status" [(ngModel)]="Status[i]">
                            <option value="1" selected>Active</option>
                            <option value="0">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                      
       </div>
```

Issue is now i want to update the values at once i can loop through the main array but how to get the dropdown and checkboxes values at each indexes and save it like:

```
  {
        "Name": "John",
        "visibility": 0,
        "IsActive": 1
    },
    {
       "Name": "Peter",
        "visibility": 1,
        "IsActive": 1
    },
    ...
```

Note: i'm using `cdk` dragdrop also so i need to loop to the whole list after sorting.

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use map to create a mapped array with the "enriched" items.

```
this.List.map((item, index) => ({ 
  ...item, 
  visibility: visibility[index], 
  isActive: Status[index] 
}))
```

Nevertheless it's not clear to me how exactly your `visibility` and `Status` properties are defined. Nevertheless it should work as you are using it in the same manner in your template.

**Notes:**

- You should watch out for naming conventions. Usually properties should start with lowercase keys
- You can also initially do the mapping and then bind in your model via `[(ngModel)]` directly instead of defining separate arrays. Separate arrays are error prone, since they could get out of sync in case of adjustments.

Comment: Thanks but `[(ngModel)]="Status[i]"`  this is not working in my case

Comment: import FormsModule in your module.

Comment: You should not just say that it's not working. You should provide the code that this not working in order to receive help. As I said to me it's not clear how `Status` and `visibility` is instantiated, but I assumed it was working, since you didn't mention anything else in your question. This way I can only guess what the actual error is.